# How to fix the pin icon visibility issue in outlook add-ins for pinnable task pane?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have a Microsoft outlook add-in for which we have recently implemented the taskpane pinning feature. The procedure specified in their official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane) was followed, after which we ran into an inconsistency with the pin icon that appears on the taskpane on successful implementation.

The pin icon was not visible on running this add-in on Outlook Desktop Client-v1811(build 11029.20108), but was visible in another machine for the same outlook client version. Microsoft's documentation enlists that this feature is supported for users on build 7668.2000 or later.

Another discrepancy was with the domains of outlook accounts. We were unable to view the icon in outlook accounts on `outlook.live.com` domain, but it was visible again when we used the Office365 domain: `outlook.office.com`.

Has anyone else come across something like this? 
Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: For the Outlook Desktop Issues, that feature should be enabled on that version. Is the Add-in not available at all? or just the pin icon? Is the SupportsPinning tag added to every Taskpane that you want the pin to show up in? Is it possible that the machines that don't have the pin icon, are on a older version of your add-in? (i.e. if you log into the SAME exchange account on the two different machines are the results different?) Do you have a sample manifest, and some screenshots of the issue (both working and not working).

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, it indeed was an issue with my manifest file. Got the pin icon on fixing the bugs. Just one more question though: Is the pin icon visible on desktop outlook versions for Calendar events too ? Unable to see it at the moment for outlook calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-in pinning is not available to `outlook.live.com` users, which is likely the cause of the issue you're seeing.